# TikZ fading out around a path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have a specific field in my diagramm, whitch I would like to leave green. 
Around that I would like it to fade into red.
By now I only found the possibility to fade inside my drawn object from red to green. I would like the fading to start just at the boundaries I set with my coordinates.
By now it looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt,ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage[pdftex] {graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{tikzit}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=10cm,
            height=7cm,
            scale only axis,
            xmin=50,
            xmax=160,
            xtick={60, 80, ..., 150},
            xlabel={test},
            xmajorgrids,
            ymin=0.75,
            ymax=1.75,
            ytick={1, 1.25,..., 1.75},
            ylabel={test},
            yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/precision=3},
            ymajorgrids
]
%
    \draw[inner color=green, outer color=red]
        plot[smooth cycle] coordinates{(90,1) (140,1) (140,1.50) (100,1.5) (80,1.25)};
%
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much for helping me[image: ![test with fading inside of the drawn path]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2Ah8.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome! Here is something that makes the boundary of any path fuzzy. This is achieved by applying multiple `postaction`s with different line widths and opacities. The number of post actions is `n` and the radius of fuzziness is `r` in

```
\path[green,fuzzy={n=40,r=20pt}]
        plot[smooth cycle] coordinates{(90,1) (140,1) (140,1.50) (100,1.5) (80,1.25)};
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt,ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\newcounter{fuzzy}
\tikzset{fuzzy/.code={\tikzset{/tikz/fuzziness/.cd,#1}%
\edef\mystyle{}\edef\fuzzynum{0}%
\loop
\ifnum\fuzzynum<\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fuzziness/n}%
\edef\fuzzynum{\the\numexpr\fuzzynum+1}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myopa}{\fuzzynum/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fuzziness/n}}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mylw}{2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fuzziness/r}*(1-\myopa)}%
\edef\mystyle{\mystyle,postaction={fill,draw,line width=\mylw pt,opacity=\myopa}}%
\repeat
\tikzset{postaction/.expanded=\mystyle}
},
fuzziness/.cd,n/.initial=10,r/.initial=10pt}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=10cm,
            height=7cm,
            scale only axis,
            xmin=50,
            xmax=175,
            xtick={60, 80, ..., 150},
            xlabel={test},
            xmajorgrids,
            ymin=0.75,
            ymax=1.75,
            ytick={1, 1.25,..., 1.75},
            ylabel={test},
            yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/precision=3},
            ymajorgrids,
            axis background/.style={fill=red},
]
    \path[green,fuzzy={n=40,r=20pt}]
        plot[smooth cycle] coordinates{(90,1) (140,1) (140,1.50) (100,1.5) (80,1.25)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can also engineer color transitions with the same strategy.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt,ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\newcounter{fuzzy}
\tikzset{color transition/.code={\tikzset{/tikz/color transition/.cd,#1}%
\edef\mystyle{}\edef\fuzzynum{0}%
\loop
\ifnum\fuzzynum<\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color transition/n}%
\edef\fuzzynum{\the\numexpr\fuzzynum+1}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myopa}{100*\fuzzynum/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color transition/n}}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mylw}{2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color transition/r}*(1-\myopa/100)}%
\edef\mycolor{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color transition/inner}!\myopa!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color transition/outer}}%
\edef\mystyle{\mystyle,postaction={fill=\mycolor,draw=\mycolor,draw,line width=\mylw pt}}%
\repeat
\tikzset{postaction/.expanded=\mystyle}
},
color transition/.cd,n/.initial=10,r/.initial=10pt,inner/.initial=black,outer/.initial=white}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=10cm,
            height=7cm,
            scale only axis,
            xmin=50,
            xmax=175,
            xtick={60, 80, ..., 150},
            xlabel={test},
            xmajorgrids,
            ymin=0.75,
            ymax=1.75,
            ytick={1, 1.25,..., 1.75},
            ylabel={test},
            yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/precision=3},
            ymajorgrids,
            axis background/.style={fill=red},
]
    \path[green,color transition={n=40,r=20pt,inner=green,outer=red}]
        plot[smooth cycle] coordinates{(90,1) (140,1) (140,1.50) (100,1.5) (80,1.25)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much (for the solution and the welcoming)! 
Unfortunatly, thats not quite what I am looking for... I want to express a specific field of parameters that are suitable for a process with the green area. Around that area in a certain range the parameters are still somewhat suitable (whitch I would like to express with the color fading). 
As far as I understand your solution gives radial shadings independent of the path I have drawn.

Comment: @Pausch I added something that makes the boundary fuzzy, which is effectively some path fading. One can easily rewrite this to yield a color transition, it needed.

Comment: Thank you so much, thats exactly what I was looking for!